# MVC Editor Templates for Date Ranges using JQuery UI DatePicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, mvc-editor-templates

I need to display JQuery UI Datepicker on most of my MVC views. So I have created a Model class for Date Range:

```
public class DateRange
{
    [DisplayName("From")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("To")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

and an editor tamplate for it:

```
@model DateRange
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FromDate)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "dateRangeFrom"})
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ToDate)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ToDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "dateRangeTo"})
```

and on my EditorHookup.js file:

```
$(function ()
{
    $('.dateRangeFrom').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $(".dateRangeTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $('.dateRangeTo').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $(".dateRangeFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
})
```

This all works perfectly unless I need two of these date range models in my view. As you can predict, this doesn't work for multiple date ranges.

Edit: The problem for example is when I close the 'From' picker on the first date range, it will set the initial date of 'To' picker on BOTH date ranges.

Any help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this could be to put both textboxes in a `<div>`. So your new editor template :

```
@model DateRange
<div>
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FromDate)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "dateRangeFrom"})
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ToDate)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ToDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "dateRangeTo"})
</div>
```

And the js should look like this :

```
$(function ()
{
    $('.dateRangeFrom').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $(this).closest("div").find(".dateRangeTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $('.dateRangeTo').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $(this).closest("div").find(".dateRangeFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
})
```

*Untested code

Hope it helps!

Comment: I know I shouldn't add a comment to say thanks, but I can't! Thanks for your answer. It worked perfectly.